# stalker script LUA ERROR attempt to index local 'outfit_now' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

The script:

```
   function update()
    
     local outfit_now = db.actor:get_current_outfit()

         if
                outfit_now:section() == "military" 

        or outfit_now:section() == "outfit_solder_m1" 
        or outfit_now:section() == "militaryspec_outfit" 
        or outfit_now:section() == "specops_outfit" 
    then 
        set_actor_community("military")
    elseif 
        outfit_now:section() == "bandit_outfit" 

        or outfit_now:section() == "bandit_master_outfit" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "bandit_veteran_outfit" 
    then
        set_actor_community("bandit")
elseif 
                outfit_now:section() == "dolg_outfit" 

        or outfit_now:section() == "dolg_black_exoskeleton" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "outfit_dolg_m1" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "dolg_heavy_outfit" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "dolg_scientific_outfit" 
              then
        set_actor_community("dolg")
elseif 
                outfit_now:section() == "killer_outfit" 

        or outfit_now:section() == "killer_blue_exoskeleton" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "killer_green_exoskeleton" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "outfit_killer_m1"          
              then
        set_actor_community("killer")
elseif changed then
        set_actor_community("actor")
elseif 
                outfit_now:section() == "svoboda_light_outfit" 

        or outfit_now:section() == "svoboda_heavy_outfit" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "outfit_svoboda_m1" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "svoboda_exoskeleton" 
              then
        set_actor_community("svoboda")
elseif 
         
outfit_now:section() == "nebo_light_outfit" 

        or outfit_now:section() == "nebo_heavy_outfit" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "nebo_scientific_outfit" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "nebo_exo_outfit" 
              then
        set_actor_community("nebo")
elseif  
                outfit_now:section() == "lastday_outfit" 

        or outfit_now:section() == "scientific_lastday_outfit" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "exo_lastday_outfit" 
                or outfit_now:section() == "nebo_exo_outfit"           
              then
        set_actor_community("lastday")
elseif  
                outfit_now:section() == "outfit_base"      
              then
        set_actor_community("actor")  

   end
end
function set_actor_community(actor)
    db.actor:set_character_community(actor)
end
```

Comment: please format your code properly...

Answer (score 0):

you're attempting to index a local nil value 'outfit_now'.

```
local outfit_now = db.actor:get_current_outfit()
```

`db.actor:get_current_outfit()` returns nil. Find out why and fix it.
If you can't don't index `outfit_now` as in `outfit_now:section()` if it is nil.